# Does BeanUtils.copyProperties make a deep clone?

Tags: java, clone, apache-commons-beanutils

To test this, I quickly whipped up the following :

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setName("A");
    Employee y = new Employee();
//  y=e;
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(y, e);
    e.setName("B");
    System.out.println(y.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}   
class Employee{
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This should have printed `A` instead it prints `null`. What went wrong here ? 
How can I really copy properties from one object to another (and not have them point to the same values), and does [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html)  create a deep copy in the first place ?

Comment: Or why Java beans is not the panacea ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your `Employee` class public.  This code worked for me (and compiles):

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.setName("A");
            Employee y = new Employee();
//  y=e;
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(y, e);
            e.setName("B");
            System.out.println(y.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class Employee {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }
}
```

When I removed the `public` from `Employee`, it printed "null".

Comment: Indeed ! I wonder how you thought the lack of public was causing a problem ? I moved 'Employee' to another class and it showed A. If I had probably implemented this as a solution to the problem I am facing (instead of making a short simple prog to see if it will work), I would never have known this can be a problem :)

Comment: Actually it was a coincidence.  I fixed this exact problem my way 10 minutes before you asked your question.